# Looking for the "future behavior" corresponding to the "R2012a" flag

Tags: matlab

The documentation pages for various functions (for example, [`categorical/intersect`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/categorical.intersect.html)) refer to a "future behavior" that can be specified by passing the `'R2012a'` flag among the arguments to those functions, but I have not been able to find a description of this behavior, and of how it differs from the behavior one gets with the alternative `'legacy'` flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In a future release, the behavior of `categorical.intersect` will change
>   to be consistent with the MATLAB® function `intersect`. [...] see the
>   documentation for [`intersect`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html).

The aforementioned documentation for `intersect` [demonstrates the difference](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html#btcnv0p-14) - the 'future' behaviour no longer guarantees to return the index of the *last* occurrence of repeated values, and the index vectors have changed from columns to rows.

That's the kind of change that can break assumptions in existing code, hence the advance warning to either test that code is robust to the future behaviour, or lock down the legacy behaviour if needed.